# Identical Dataframes Asserting Not Equal - Python Pandas

Tags: python, unit-testing, pandas, dataframe, python-unittest

I am trying to unit test my code. I have a method that given a MySQL query, returns the result as a pandas dataframe. Note that in the database, all returned values in `created` and `external_id` are NULL. Here is the test:

```
def test_get_data(self):

    ### SET UP

    self.report._query = "SELECT * FROM floor LIMIT 3";
    self.report._columns = ['id', 'facility_id', 'name', 'created', 'modified', 'external_id']
    self.d = {'id': p.Series([1, 2, 3]),
              'facility_id': p.Series([1, 1, 1]),
              'name': p.Series(['1st Floor', '2nd Floor', '3rd Floor']),
              'created': p.Series(['None', 'None', 'None']),
              'modified': p.Series([datetime.strptime('2012-10-06 01:08:27', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                                    datetime.strptime('2012-10-06 01:08:27', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                                    datetime.strptime('2012-10-06 01:08:27', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]),
              'external_id': p.Series(['None', 'None', 'None'])
              }
    self.df = p.DataFrame(data=self.d, columns=['id', 'facility_id', 'name', 'created', 'modified', 'external_id'])
    self.df.fillna('None')
    print(self.df)
    ### CODE UNDER TEST

    result = self.report.get_data(self.report._cursor_web)
    print(result)
    ### ASSERTIONS

    assert_frame_equal(result, self.df)
```

Here is the console output (note the print statements in the test code. The manually constructed dataframe is on top, the one derived from the function being tested is on the bottom):

```
.   id  facility_id       name created            modified external_id
0   1            1  1st Floor    None 2012-10-06 01:08:27        None
1   2            1  2nd Floor    None 2012-10-06 01:08:27        None
2   3            1  3rd Floor    None 2012-10-06 01:08:27        None
   id  facility_id       name created            modified external_id
0   1            1  1st Floor    None 2012-10-06 01:08:27        None
1   2            1  2nd Floor    None 2012-10-06 01:08:27        None
2   3            1  3rd Floor    None 2012-10-06 01:08:27        None
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_data (__main__.ReportTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file/ReportsTestCase.py", line 46, in test_get_data
    assert_frame_equal(result, self.df)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 1313, in assert_frame_equal
obj='DataFrame.iloc[:, {0}]'.format(i))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 1181, in assert_series_equal
obj='{0}'.format(obj))
  File "pandas/src/testing.pyx", line 59, in pandas._testing.assert_almost_equal (pandas/src/testing.c:4156)
  File "pandas/src/testing.pyx", line 173, in pandas._testing.assert_almost_equal (pandas/src/testing.c:3274)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 1018, in raise_assert_detail
raise AssertionError(msg)
```

AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 3] are different

```
DataFrame.iloc[:, 3] values are different (100.0 %)
[left]:  [None, None, None]
[right]: [None, None, None]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.354s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

By my reckoning, column 'created' contains three string values of 'None' in both the left and right dataframes. Why is it asserting not equal?

Comment: Maybe one of them is not the string `"None"` but just NoneType [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html)?

Comment: @ayhan that was it, thank you! I hadn't yet encountered NoneType. Please post your answer as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python also has a built-in constant `None` that is different from the string `'None'`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html):

> None
>
> The sole value of the type NoneType. None is frequently used to
>   represent the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not
>   passed to a function. Assignments to None are illegal and raise a
>   SyntaxError.

In the case of comparing `None`  against `'None'` (`None == 'None'`) the result will be False. Therefore, `assert_frame_equal` will raise an AssertionError if one of the DataFrames contains `None`  but the other contains `'None'`.